# Use a generated array column specification in summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I am pretty inexperienced in R, so excuse me if this a non-sense question.

I want to do the following:

I want to summarize a bunch of groups using  `group_by(key) %>% summarise`. What I want to use to summarize is not a straightforward mean but also not something absolutely complex and there are a lot of columns I want to reduce, so I don't want to write them it by hand. 
I have a function that returns a list of string of the columns I want to be passed as an argument to `summarize` in the form `"new_column_name = some_column[some_filter]"`.
I attach an example for clarification.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

columns <- function() {
  columns = c()
  for(i in 1:2) {
    for (m in c("mean", "sd")) {
        v1 = str_interp("${m}_column_${i}_boolean_true = ${m}(column_${i}[ b == TRUE])")
        v2 = str_interp("${m}_column_${i}_boolean_false = ${m}(column_${i}[ b == FALSE])")
        columns = c(columns, v1)
        columns = c(columns, v2)
    }
  }
  return(columns)
}

data <- data.frame(key=c("key1", "key1", "key2", "key2"), "column_1" = 1:4, "column_2" = c(21,15,9, 18), "b" = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)) 
g = data %>% 
    group_by(key) %>% 
    summarise(group_size = n(),
            prop_of_TRUE = sum(b == TRUE) / n(), 
            prop_of_FALSE = sum(b == FALSE) / n(),
            some_magic( columns())

        )
```

I would like to be able to use the output of `columns()` as the input of `summarize`. The output of `columns()` looks like this:

```
"mean_column_1_boolean_true = mean(column_1[ b == TRUE])"  
"mean_column_1_boolean_false = mean(column_1[ b == FALSE])"
"sd_column_1_boolean_true = sd(column_1[ b == TRUE])"      
...
```

I wish there was `some_magic` function that does some kind of array unpacking and string conversion to some kind of quotation expression.

I tried with a lot of combinations of `quo`, `sym` and `!!!` but nothing seems to work, especially because I have not a clear understanding of what I am doing when I am using them.

### Edited

Using the dataframe I defined earlier, what I want to accomplish is the same as doing this:

```r
data <- data.frame(key=c("key1", "key1", "key2", "key2"), 
                   "column_1" = 1:4, 
                   "column_2" = c(21,15,9, 18), 
                   "b" = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE))
g = data %>% 
    group_by(key) %>% 
    summarise(group_size = n(),
            prop_of_TRUE = sum(b == TRUE) / n(), 
            prop_of_FALSE = sum(b == FALSE) / n(),
            mean_column_1_boolean_true = mean(column_1[ b == TRUE]), 
            mean_column_1_boolean_false = mean(column_1[ b == FALSE]),
            sd_column_1_boolean_true = sd(column_1[ b == TRUE]),
            sd_column_1_boolean_false = sd(column_1[ b == FALSE]),   
            mean_column_2_boolean_true = mean(column_2[ b == TRUE]), 
            mean_column_2_boolean_false = mean(column_2[ b == FALSE]),
            sd_column_2_boolean_true = sd(column_2[ b == TRUE]),
            sd_column_2_boolean_false = sd(column_2[ b == FALSE])
        )
```

but without having to write every column

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some minimal amount of data so that we can attempt to apply what your wanting to accomplish to a common set of data as well as test to see if your desired output is being produced. 

Consider editing your question to include a section of that creates a data frame using representative data and also try to include an illustrative example of what you want the output to be afterward. Here is a straight forward example of creating a data frame in R. https://www.dummies.com/programming/r/how-to-create-a-data-frame-from-scratch-in-r/

Comment: There is a data.frame defined in the example in the variable data. I added a clarification at the end, just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `rlang::parse_exprs()` on the output of the `columns()` function.  The entire expression is used as the new column names so these need to be cleaned up.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
library(stringr)

h <- data %>% 
  group_by(key) %>% 
  summarise(group_size = n(),
            prop_of_TRUE = sum(b == TRUE) / n(), 
            prop_of_FALSE = sum(b == FALSE) / n(),
            !!!parse_exprs(columns())) %>%
  rename_at(vars(contains("=")), str_remove, " = .*")

identical(g, h)
[1] TRUE
```

That said, what you're trying to achieve, at least from this example, could also be fairly easily achieved through regular `dplyr` verbs.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the parse_exprs. What I am trying to do is a bit more complex compared to the example, but I will try to do it using a more dplyr standard way.